# Letter Ordering

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I am struggling when to use combinations and permutations. I know I have seen these questions on here, but my pertain of when to correctly apply combinations or permutations.

I know permutations deals with ordering, and combinations deal with grouping (putting the definitions crudely).

**Questions**

How different linear arrangements are there of the letters $A,B,C,D,E,F$ for which:

a) $A$ and $B$ are next to each other?

b) $A$ is before $B$?

c) $A$ is before $B$, and $C$ is before $D$?

**My Answers**

a) I cannot think of a way to use combinations correctly with this questions, but we see that $AB$ and $BA$ can be used and had $2!$ arrangements, and with the remaining spots there is $5!$ arrangements, leaving us with an answer of $5! \times 2!$

b) $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}$ explaination is as follows, we choose $A$ and then $B$ from our six letters, then for each letter we place it.

c) $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}$ explaination is as follows, we choose $A$ then $B$, after that we choose $C$ and then $D$, then the rest of this is placed.

**My Questions**

- We used these questions in class as examples, but they were slightly modified. In class my professor likes to do most of this using combinations, but when I am doing this in the book, the author likes to use permutations. Is this a correct way to use combinations?
- Can the first question (a) be answered using combinations?
- Lastly, why should I use combinations in this case when permutation can get the job done?

Comment: Writing 
$$
4! = \binom{4}{1} \binom{3}{1} \binom{2}{1} \binom{1}{1},
$$
etc., always works, but it looks unnecessarily complicated IMHO.

Comment: For **(b)** note that in every permutation either $A$ comes before $B$ or vice versa, so there's a bijection from the set of permutations with $A$ before $B$ to the set of permutations with $B$ before $A$ given by swapping the two letters. Hence, the number of such is just half of $6!$, which agrees with your answer.

Comment: Along similar lines, for **(c)** you can divide the set of all $6!$ permutations into $4$ equal-sized subsets based on the $4$ possibilities of choosing $A$ before $B$ or not and also choosing $C$ before $D$ or not. Hence, there's one fourth of $6!$ such permutations, which again agrees with your answer.

Comment: The question specifically asks for permutations ("linear arrangements"). Your professor is doing you a disservice when working it out any other way.